# How to update the already existing dictionary with new key, values and save them for future use in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, append, addition

Currently I'm reading Automate The Boring Stuff with Python book, in Chapter 5 Dictionaries and Structuring Data, they explains the code of birthdays.py, it has a dictionary of birthday names and their birthday dates, if the name entered exists in the dictionary then it will return its value, if the entered name not in the dictionary, then it asks for their new name and date, and then upload it to birthdays database(dictionary),so the problem is, after close that program and again running it, it forget about that new name and date, so how can we add/append/update that already existing birthdays dictionary with new names, dates for future use.
In chapter 8 Reading and Writing Files(Automate The Boring Stuff With Python), they mention shelve module but I do not understand it.

I'm a noob. Hope someone will clarify my doubt in this platform StackOverFlow.

Edit:
Here's my code, I want to update new names and dates using input method and store them into a new variables and then update the dictionary.
So, if you don't mind, help me to solve this.

```
birthdays = {'MARK': 'Nov 11', 'LEONARDO': 'May 22', 'ELON': 'Jul 3', 'ZAYN': 'Oct 18', 'JOHN': 'Dec 30'}
while True:
    name = input("Enter name:(or leave a blank to quit) \n").upper()
    if name == '':
        print('NO NAME ENTERED')
        break
    if name in birthdays:
        print(birthdays[name] + ' is the birthday of ' + name)

    else:
        print('THE NAME YOU ENTERED IS NOT IN THE BIRTHDAYS DATABASE')
        print('-----------------------------------------------------')
        print('Anyways,you can still add it to the DATABASE')
        print('What is their birthday? (or enter to quit)')
        bday = input()
        if bday == '':
            break
        else:
            birthdays[name] = bday
            print('BIRTHDAYS DATABASE NOW UPDATED!!!')
```

Finally, it's working...,I made it.:)
Here's my version of that code...correct me if I'm wrong.

```
import pickle


#PROGRAM TO STORE AND RETRIVE ALREADY STORED BIRTHDAY DATE & NAMES
#IF ENTERED NAME NOT EXIST IN THE BIRTHDAYS DICTIONARY THEN IT ASKS AND STORE(APPEND) THAT NEW VALUE TO ALREADY EXISTING DICTIONARY.



dict1 = {} #you can also write your names and dates here, this will also works
while True:
    name = input('Enter name: \n').upper()
    if name == '':
        print('No Name Entered')
        break
     
    
    try:
        readFile = open('final_file','rb')
        updated_dict = pickle.load(readFile)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    

    if  name in dict1:
        print('Found In Default Dictionary,')
        print(name +'\'s'+ ' birthday is on ',dict1[name])
    if name in updated_dict:
        print('Found In Updated Dictionary,')
        print(name +'\'s'+ ' birthday is on ',updated_dict[name])      
        data = input('Type \'data\' to see database: (or enter to none) \n')
        if data == 'data':
            print(updated_dict)
        else:
            pass

        
        exit_door = input('Type \'e\' to exit or enter to continue: ')
        if exit_door == 'e':
            break
        else:
            pass
    else:    
        print('Not found, you can add it')
        bday = input('What\'s their bday?(like Nov 23) ')
        
        #THIS WILL ADD NEW NAMES AND DATES TO ALREADY EXISTING DICTIONARY
        appendFile = open('final_file','wb')
        updated_dict[name] = bday
        appDict = updated_dict      
        pickle.dump(appDict,appendFile)
        print('Updated!'.center(20,'*'))
        appendFile.close()
```

Comment: You can use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) for serializing and de-serializing a Python object. Create a file using this, next time load the same file.

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply, I tried with pickle, but when I append new values/dictionary using 'ab' in pickle, and try to load that file, it displaying the dictionary without appended dictionary/values. So how to get all the appended dictionaries/values while loading that file.

Answer (score 2):

You could write your dictionary to a json file:

```
import json

dict = {"name": "Alice",
"birthday": "12/01/2020"
}

with open('file.txt', 'w') as json_file:
  json.dump(dict, json_file)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I want to append new dictionary with new names and values to the previous dictionary. So can you help me with the code that I edited in the question.